# How to use same modal code in all the pages?

Tags: html, authentication, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a HTML project consisting of 5 pages. I have a login button in every page where I am using a modal. It uses id of the modal div.

`<li> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">LOGIN</button></li>`

but i've to copy paste the modal code in every page. 
Is there a way to not paste the complete modal div in every page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggnetion is to use jquery here is some code snippet

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#includedContent").load("button.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
 <div id="includedContent"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

For button you can put your code in #includedContent div.
Aou have to put script code  js file . i.e "button.js"

And include that js file in every page where you need to have login button.
and #includedContent div.

hope so this will help you